# How can I use R to generate Plot like this? What library should be used?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

[image: I want to create plot with interaction like following]

In this plot, I first use geom_point() in ggplot2, and it can create the symbol. But I also want to add some tag in these symbol which shows some information such as date and time, like the picture shows. And I want to create a line between two symbol, to show the begin and end of an event. And lastly, I want use Shiny to create an APP and I can interact with it. Is this possible? If yes, how can I do it? Should I use ggplot2 or timevis? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This sounds like three or four questions. I think you will have more luck getting useful answers in this forum if you have specific questions rather than a spec list.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a highly customised graph so there will be a lot of steps to achieve your goal.

One bit though for the horizontal lines...

You can do the lines as line segments, the closest to this is a lollipop graph.

There is an example of this [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/303-lollipop-plot-with-2-values.html). You can customise the start and end shapes based on whatever you want, or plot a separate graph of the shapes on top of the lines.